# Ubuntu Unable to execute No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, sudo

Installed Ubuntu and get this error. Latest Python package installed

**Command:** sudo ./Task1.py

**Error:**
sudo: unable to execute ./Task1.py: No such file or directory

Working Command:

- sudo
- chmod +x Task1.py
- gedit Task1.py

but sudo ./Task1.py not working can anyone help me

Thank you

Comment: I suspect you've got `#!/some/path` as the first line of the file, and the "no such file or directory" refers to the first line. But it's a wild guess since you don't show your Python file

Answer (score 0):

First run `ls` which will list the files/folders in your current path.
If task.py is listed, doing `python task.py` should run the file.

Comment: yes, gedit commands work so the file is there.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Several ways:

1. use `pwd` to show dir address.
2. use `ls | grep py` to see whether it is there.

Comment: Tried this command but not solve issue

Comment: @Gaurav how about `python3 this_file.py` ?

Comment: I have to start mininet so I have to use sudo, otherwise mininet not start and file not work